# Rails quitting loop but not logging anything even though rescue StandardError is present - mystery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rescue

I have a method like so:

```
  def self.perform
    total_done = 0

    all_user_roles = UserRole.all
    user_roles_count = all_user_roles.count

    Rails.logger.info "Going to loop #{user_roles_count} times"

    all_user_roles.each do |user_role|
      Rails.logger.info "starting the loop..."

      if user_role.invalid?
        Rails.logger.info "Skipping, role invalid."
        next
      end

      role_name = RoleService.send(
        :role_name,
        role: user_role[:role],
        project: user_role.project
      )

      existing_role = RoleService.get_for_user(user_role.user, project: user_role.project)
      if existing_role.present?
        Rails.logger.info "Skipping role because it already exists."
        next
      end

      RoleService.set_for_user(
        user_role.user,
        project: user_role.project
      )

      migrated_roles += 1
    end

    Rails.logger.info "DONE"
  rescue StandardError => e
    Rails.logger.error("Error!")
  end
```

To my surprise, I see it should loop 1000 times:

```
>>> Going to loop 1000 times
```

...but neither the DONE message nor the Error at the end are logged. I see it runs 105 times, and then no more messages in the log.

What could be happening here? Is there a way for something to be raised from one of those service calls and not be caught by the general `rescue` at the end?

I'm running out of ideas...

Thanks!

Comment: How long did you wait? Loading 1000 records into RAM and initializing instances might take some time depending on your data.

Comment: The thing is for each loop it prints the "starting the loop΅ message, but after 105 and 30 minutes later, no more messages... and I can't find out how could the execution leave this method without logging one of the two final messages.

Comment: @EdyBourne are you sure it does leave this method? perhaps some line is blocking for a very long time. If you see "starting the loop..." but nothing more, add some more log lines, one after every line of application code and see which is the last line you get.

Comment: Another thought, is you could try changing StandardError to Exception which is not normally what you want, but it may be possible that you're running into an exception which is not descending from StandardError.

Comment: I can see three problems with this code. The first is that you're not batch loading the records, the second is that `RoleService.get_for_user` will very likely cause a N+1 query - you should be considering eager loading or even adding a condition to the initial query to weed out the records that you don't need to do anything with. The thirds is that the method is just too dang long.

Comment: Start by just using `all_user_roles.find_each(batch_size: 100)` and play with the batch size so it doesn't halt and timeout.